# Dilemma with duplicate rows in php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

I know the duplicate question has been asked before but my situation is slightly different. First. I'm a real novice when it comes to php/mysqli so please make sure your comments are explained for a dummy.

Ok... I have a game with a registration script with table. Works great. I also have an orders script and table. So someone buys my game. It is a requirement that they use an email address when purchasing. I have an email address field in the game registration. Buyers must use the same email address to register as that used for purchase.

Now here is my dilemma. I can get the script to check if the email is the same for purchase and registration and throw an error if not. It also checks if there are duplicate usernames in the users table.
However, I can't figure out how to stop it adding duplicate emails to the users table.
Say someone buys my game. They register and all is good. There is nothing stopping them from sending the game link to a friend and telling them the email address used. That second person could then register a new username but of course the email address is the same.

I need to prevent this happening. I can do either (check against both tables or check for duplicates) but not both. I would think perhaps I may have to create a seperate table for email addresses? But then how to tell it to delete the most recent entry if indeed there are duplicates.

```
if ($todo == "reg") { 

$buycheck = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM $nameTable2 WHERE       email='$email' "); 

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM $nameTable WHERE username = '$username'  ");  

   if (!$result) { 
      $msg = ((is_object($connect)) ? mysqli_error($connect) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)); 
      $string = 'valid=0&err=query fail'; 
   }  

   else if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) { 
      $msg = ((is_object($connect)) ? mysqli_error($connect) : (($___mysqli_res = mysqli_connect_error()) ? $___mysqli_res : false)); 
      $string = 'valid=0&err=double data'; 

   } 

   else if (mysqli_num_rows($buycheck)== 1 ) {


    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO $nameTable (id,username,userpass,email)"); 

 $string = 'valid=1';
 }


else {
$string = 'valid=10&err= error: email differs ';
}

}
```

Where nameTable2 is orders and nameTable is users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: and you're saying that this works `mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO $nameTable (id,username,userpass,email)");` or is this a *"fill in the blanks for me"* ?

Comment: *"I can't figure out how to stop it adding duplicate emails to the game table"* - add a UNIQUE constraint. edit and do as Michael said below.

Comment: A `VALUES` clause is missing from that `INSERT`...  What is the table definition of the `$nameTable` table?  Please post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE that_table`.  You could, for example, add a unique index on the email column there, and check for errors on insert.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski [GMTA...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603205/dilemma-with-duplicate-rows-in-php-and-mysqli#comment56952205_34603205) by mere seconds lol Edit: like I said ;-)

Comment: Fred I tried adding unique and yes it prevents the duplicate from being added but it then it outputs the string as being valid when it is not.

Comment: then try a reverse psychology and handle it in a different way. IF EXISTs... do something else. Edit: Maybe @MichaelBerkowski has a few ideas as to what it is you want to do here.

Comment: I test the php like so... my_domain/testsql.php?todo=reg&email=cvb@def.com&email=cvb@def.com&username=test5&userpass=123

Comment: OMG! you're passing usernames/emails and passwords in a GET?! ***danger*** - not to mention that you're open to an SQL injection here.

Comment: If there's a unique constraint violation on the `INSERT` (email already exists), you can check the return value of `mysqli_query()` there and only on success, do you output valid.  `if (mysqli_query($con, "INSERT...")) { $string = 'valid=1'; } else { // invalid message! }`

Comment: Fred you are scaring me! How do you know its GET?